# SVD approximation, construction of the matrix A such that A=USV*

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I want to construct a matrix $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ such that $\textbf{A} = \textbf{US}\textbf{V}^{\ast}$.

My goal is to do reverse SVD after I select the desired singular values for my matrix. During my research I have encountered this technique but the matrices that they choose for $\textbf{U}$,$\textbf{V}$ are $\textbf{I}_{m}$ and $\textbf{I}_{n}$ respectively.

This doesn't really make sense to me because you are basically constructing a diagonal matrix $\textbf{A}=\textbf{S}$.

Is there another way to construct the matrix $\textbf{A}$ without it being diagonal?

Comment: If you want $A$ to not be diagonal, you should choose $U$ and $V$ to not be identity matrices.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, thanks for your comment. Maybe I was unclear with the problem that I am facing. The question is how can I choose U and V such that they oblige to the SVD approximation, i.e. be unitary and be the left and the right singular vectors respectively.

Comment: @Mihaths It is unclear where your difficulty is. You have $U$ and $V$, and you want to construct a matrix $A$ for which $A$ has an SVD of the form $A = U S V^*$.  To do so, simply select a non-negative diagonal matrix $S$ and compute $USV^*$, then take this matrix to be your $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for your comment, maybe I am a little bit confused regarding how to choose U and V, because from the definition of SVD, U is the left singular vectors and V is the matrix with the right singular vectors.

Comment: @Mihaths $U$ and $V$ can be any unitary matrices. If you know what the singular vectors are supposed to be (or if you have selected singular vectors), then the left singular vectors are the columns of $U$, while the right singular vectors are the columns of $V$.